# Create helper to test for non-empty values

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to write a helper method that tests the object for some condition and TS will be happy with this test, following doesnt work:

```
interface TestB {
  propA: string[] | undefined;
}
interface TestA {
  list: TestB[] | null;
  propB: number[] | undefined;
}
const isOK = (arg: TestA): boolean => {
  return arg.propB !== undefined && arg.list !== null;
};
const testA: TestA = { list: null, propB: [1] };
const a: TestB[] | undefined = testA && isOK(testA) ? testA.list : undefined;
console.log(a);
```

It shows the following error

> Type 'TestB[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'TestB[] |
>   undefined'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'TestB[] |
>   undefined'.ts(2322)

However if I add the test:
`const a: TestB[] | undefined =
  testA && isOK(testA) && testA.list ? testA.list : undefined;` TS compiler is happy. Is there a way to make a helper in such way that TS will be satisfied? In the `isOK` helper I already test the `testA.list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the `isOK()` function as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).  As you noticed, the compiler *does* understand that checking `arg.propB !== undefined && arg.list !== null` has implications for the type of `arg`, as part of its [control flow type analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis).  However, such analysis only holds inside the scope where the check is happening, and is not automatically [propagated out of function calls](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10734).  It turns out that automated control flow analysis has some [inherent tradeoffs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) and we have to put up with at least some amount of false positives (it warns on good code), false negatives (it doesn't warn on bad code), or bad performance (it takes forever to decide if code is good or bad).

Luckily enough, there is a way for you to *tell* the compiler that a `boolean`-returning function acts as a type guard on one of its arguments: a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). Instead of annotating that the function returns `boolean`, you annotate a return type of `x is Y` where `x` is the name of one of the arguments to the function, and `Y` is a type narrower than the type of `x`.  For example:

```
const isOK = (arg: TestA): arg is { propB: number[]; list: TestB[] } => {
  return arg.propB !== undefined && arg.list !== null;
};
```

Now the compiler will understand if you call `isOK(arg)` and it returns `true`, then `arg` is narrower than just `TestA`, and is now a `{propB: number[]; list: TestB[]}`.  Then the rest of your code should compile with no warnings as you intended:

```
const a: TestB[] | undefined = testA && isOK(testA) ? testA.list : undefined; // okay
```

Allow me to reiterate how lucky it is that your `isOK` function can be turned into a user-defined type guard with just a change in the type annotation.   Often there are validation checking techniques which work just fine in JavaScript but which are not really supported by TypeScript, and one needs to significantly refactor that code to make the compiler happy (or one uses a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to simply silence the compiler's objections).  But this seems to be one of those fortuitous occasions where it feels like the language designers anticipated your specific use case and addressed it. What luck!

Hope that helps!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gELIN4BQyyADlAPYkCCAXMllKAOYDaAusgD7ICuIAJhBigI-ANwEAvgVCRYiFOixV8RZABtgWOkpzsuyED3XqJxMpWx0jAWwBG0fdz6DhIUROkJyILMi0A8gDSyAC8yAAUcFBMOphgVACUdNFM-hj4pBQkVoY89o5sYhpaYHFY2PqSYQB8qsRQEGA8UCDIqQB0FjnIAISh4S5CIvzIAGRj7TEdmn794UYmnhLevmDIkMrlCWGZs2V5JgA0WZZ0LACMHJIrPn5w25UczgLD7qPhmzsT6cERX0lkAB+DbxKgzUrIOhDNweAirDDkdQQGbkJhRRISIA)

Comment: I love it:) this was a test case code and my real types were much bigger but basically all I had to do is to use Pick on the `arg` and choose props that are used in the predicate's type `(arg: Pick<TestA, 'propB' | 'list'>): arg is { propB: number[]; list: TestB[] }`